# How to create generated columns in DB2/400

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I wanna create a virtual column which concatenates two columns to 1. My attempt was:

```sql
--result sqlstate 42601 -104 (Token not valid: (. Valid token: IDENTITY)
alter table schema.table
  add column name1_v generated always as (trim(name1) || ' ' || trim(vt_alt))
  add column vtKuTx_v generated always as (trim(vtKuTx) || ' ' || trim(vt_alt))
;
```

This should work according to the docs. ( https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_73/db2/rbafzpdf.pdf?view=kc ) (page 851).
Has anyone an idea how to get this done?

Thanks in advance.

edit:
I doublechecked it. This doesn't work either.

```sql
create or replace table table.schema (
  number int default 2,
  square int generated always as (number * number)
);
```

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Token not valid: (. Valid token: IDENTITY

Comment: What is the version of the i-series ?

Comment: With Db2-for-i , The following restriction is documented "GENERATED can be specified only if the column has a ROWID data type (or a distinct type that is based on a ROWID data type), the column is an identity column, identity-options are specified, as-row-transaction-timestamp-clause is specified, as-row-transaction-start-id-clause is specified, or the column is a row change timestamp."

Comment: I tested on 7.2 and 7.4. The values of the error messages differ sligtly. 7.4 awaits a special register 7.2 an identity.

Comment: Ok I'll just create a view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always give your Db2 version (or in this case , the version of the i series ) when asking for help.

As you are using Db2 for i, you should study the documentation for [ALTER TABLE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/db2/rbafzatabl.htm) for that i series platform , and then choose the correct version of the i series software on that page.

For the GENERATED clause of `ALTER TABLE` the i-series documentation specifies the following restriction in Note 5:

> 5 GENERATED can be specified only if the column has a ROWID data type
> (or a distinct type that is based on a ROWID data type), the column is
> an identity column, identity-options are specified,
> as-row-transaction-timestamp-clause is specified,
> as-row-transaction-start-id-clause is specified, or the column is a
> row change timestamp.

That may be the reason for your -104 exception. So you will need to find an alternate method to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
ALTER TABLE schema.table
  ADD COLUMN name1_v  DEFAULT trim(name1) || ' ' || trim(vt_alt)
  ADD COLUMN vtKuTx_v DEFAULT trim(vtKuTx) || ' ' || trim(vt_alt)
;
```

Here, I found a tutorial to that ...
https://www.db2tutorial.com/db2-basics/db2-alter-table-add-column/

Comment: Nice attempt but it doesn't update the column when name1 is updated.

Comment: I suppose it works like all DBMSs I worked with.

Comment: Adding a column to a table is a DDL operation. Modifying the contents of a given column in a given row of a table is a DML operation. There are other databases that have a REFRESH functionality, which will reflect the changes in the source column to the target columns when triggered. Or you could introduce a trigger that fires when you update a source column. If you want to do it just with the table definition, however, all you can do is ALTER TABLE ... DROP COLUMN ... and ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN ... again

Comment: the trigger would be a nice solution. These columns will conntain accumulated data for our BI system. So i decided to make a view for the importer to keep the embedded statement as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: This answer is for DB2 LUW, not DB2-400. Maybe the same reasoning applies.**

DB2 prevents you to add a column inadvertently because this can be a very heavy operation. Instead DB2 forces you to:

- Disable the constraints.
- Add the columns.
- Enable the constraints again.

As a DB2 SQL Compiler Developer states (sic):

> Adding/altering a generated column is the only table action
> which physically updates the table. To be more precise it will likely
> update all zillion rows of it (which can be a lot in Viper with range
> partitioning).
>
> So rather than quitely filling up peoples logspace (or stressing the
> auto-archival option) we decided it would be appropriate to perform such
> heavy operations while the table is in check pending.

Therefore, you can do it as:

```
set integrity for schema.table off;

alter table schema.table
  add column name1_v generated as (trim(name1) || ' ' || trim(vt_alt))
  add column vtKuTx_v generated as (trim(vtKuTx) || ' ' || trim(vt_alt))
;

set integrity for schema.table immediate checked force generated;
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=8c755e3615dfb3b20c0f893b81baec05).

Comment: It doesn't work. But thanks for the db fiddle link i wasn't aware of the website.